# compile-time safe array in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

There's this homework question i've been wrecking my brain about:

I have to create an array class in C++ in which an index access to an element in the array is checked in compile-time, i.e. if I try to access the array with an index outside ita size it will cause a compilation error.

I thought I'd use enums as indexes instead of ints, but I spoke with my instructor and he told me that it's not the correct way, he also said that "think that for the same price you could use this to have an array where the indexes don't start at 0" or something like that.

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: You can not possibly report such error in places where the indexing is done using a variable, because most probably its value will only be known during runtime.

Answer (score 8):

`std::array` from C++11 is just what you ask. It's an array with compile-time known size, which allows compile time checking out-of-bounds errors

Example:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::get<3>(arr); // returns 4;
std::get<9>(arr); // COMPILE ERROR
```

Internally this array is implemented using templated array size (as you see from example, the second template argument in first line) and `static_assert` which performs compile-time checking for your condition (in this case it would be `index < array_size`). Also as you see in example you are using std::get instead of operator[], because, again, it uses templated argument as index, which has to be a constant expression (`constexpr`) to allow  compile-time checking instead of run-time.

If you need a variable index, you can use old good operator[] but you won't have compile-time out-of-bounds checking which is clearly impossible to do at all.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't really explain how to *create* such class.

Comment: I added a little bit of explanation

Comment: thanks! but i'm pretty sure i can't use static_assert since it does pretty much exactly what i'm expected to do on my own

Comment: @dog Implementing your own `static_assert` is a whole different story alltogheter, requiring a bit of TMP fiddling, at least.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint: If you want to check *values* at compile time, you essentially only have one option: you need to use non-type template arguments.

The standard library type [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) implements his, so check it out for inspiration on how to solve this.

Comment: Generally speaking your first sentence is not true - you can also use static_assert with constexpr values.

Comment: @sasha.sochka Sure. I wrote that in the context of calling a function at runtime and *passing parameters* into it. `constexpr` would work if it were allowed on function arguments.

Comment: This is allowed. Simple example: `constexpr int sqr(int val) { return val * val; }
int arr[sqr(3)];`

Comment: @sasha.sochka Too hasty again. Of course that works. But `sqr` couldn’t be a member function operating on a non-`constexpr` object.

Comment: Ehhm, perhaps that doesn't really make sense anymore in the context of the original question but you can make `sqr` a member function operating on a non-constexpr object (returning non-constexpr obviously)

Answer (score 1):

A hint, maybe phrased a bit differently: if you want to check the index at compile time, its value must also be known at compile time. Now, how to pass something to, say, a function at *compile time*?

To signal an error at compile time, `static_assert` can be used rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a chance to use a custom class as the index type. You can then limit the generation of an index element by limiting the operators of the class. Especially this can ensure that no user input can be used as an index (if you don't provide any method to convert an integer (or similar) to the index type. If you allow this, you have no chance at all!).

Comment: i think this is what he meant, but i don't know how to make a class that has limited generations (a number which somehow the compiler knows about? )

this is a quote from a lecture slide:   "Array references: it is impossible to detect overflow of array indices.
Impossible when indices are of type integer – not if the type of the
indices corresponds to the array size (which must be part of the
type of the array)."

Comment: The quote from your lecture slides leads me to the assumption, that a template-driven solution might be expected (as @sasha_sochka noted).