# Static bound checking for array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, static-code-analysis

I'm in need for some guidance regarding a question from a programming languages course I'm taking.

We need to come up with a way to implement an array class in C++, so that accessing it's element is statically checked for overflow.
We are not to use C++11 (static assertion) nor any other black-box solution - this is a theoretical question, not something I need for coding purposes.

we did get a strong hint in the lecture slides :

"
it is impossible to detect overflow of array indices when indices are of type integer – not if the type of the indices corresponds to the array size (which must be part of the type of the array).
"

I thought about using fixed-length (array size) string for indices, but other than thinking about the option I really did not get much :(.

Clarification: OK, this has got some confused replies to it, probably because I was unclear - So I will re-emphasize:

1. "Statically" means "at compile time". The *compiler* should alert the user of the overflow (Warning/Error..). Not runtime!
2. Read the "hint" given to us - it's to be used. specifically, the program may NOT check for bounds! specifically the at() method of arrays in c++ is not to be used or emulated.

In light of all this what I am thinking they want is some sort of transformation 
int->(Indices type)
that somehow fails or computes wrong values for these indices in case the array is overflowed.

Hope that is clearer now. Thank you's

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly (which I'm probably not) you can get a good hint/clue from std::vector's at() method if you want to create an array class that has a kind of built-in bounds-checking.  It's supposed to throw an exception if the user tries to access an element that is out of bounds.  I'm not going to bother providing you code but still, I hope it helps as a guideline

Comment: It sounds like he's asking you to reinvent [`std::array::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at)?

Comment: I think your question need rephrasing. A class can not staticly check itself. And while in theory it's possible to make functions with static checks, I doubt they would be any useful. Probably you wanted to ask something else, like runtime bounds checks?

Comment: what do you mean by "statically checked"?  do you want compilation to fail? or do you just want to determine it at compile time and indicate the out-of-bounds at runtime?

Comment: [Maybe he means like this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=61fd2f2b5fea42a2ac431a711f4816f3-803889f054654ad4b92ce24ea171578e)

Comment: @MooingDuck I was just about to suggest that. But he says "We are not to use C++11 (static assertion)". I'm wracking my brain trying to think of how to do this WITHOUT static assertion (or an imitation of it).

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter: I don't believe the code I linked has a `static_assert` or C++11.  But he specifically requests that "accessing it's element is statically checked for overflow", what else could it be besides an assert or exception?  (Actually, exception would have been easier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1c5354ffac136806f8aacae8c561d36d-803889f054654ad4b92ce24ea171578e)

Comment: added some explanation... thanks all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [compile-time safe array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296866/compile-time-safe-array-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe he intends for you to index the array based on a type where the value is part of the type, such as `std::integral_constant<int, value>`.  Using this, the size can be checked at compile time.  However, without `static_assert`, it's hard to think of simple ways to assert that one constant is smaller than another.

Here, I use the trick of comparing if the index is less than the size, converting that to an integer (0 if it's out of bounds, or 1 otherwise), multiplying that by two and subtracting one, giving either (-1 for out of bounds, or 1 for valid), and then making an array of that size.  This causes a compilation error if the index is out of bounds, and is optimized out if the index is valid.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, int count>
struct array {
    array() : data() {}

    template<int N>
    T& operator[](std::integral_constant<int,N> index) {
        //compiler error if index is too small
        char index_is_too_large[(N<count)*2-1]={}; 
        index_is_too_large[0] = index_is_too_large[0]; 
        //second line makes the compiler ignore warnings

        return data[N];
    }
private:
    T data[count];
};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    array<float, 3> thingy;

    std::integral_constant<int, 2> index2;
    std::cout << thingy[index2] << '\n';

    std::integral_constant<int, 3> index3;
    std::cout << thingy[index3] << '\n'; //COMPILER ERROR ON THIS LINE
}
```

This seems quite advanced for the restrictions placed on you, I think it's more likely you misunderstood your professor somewhere along the line.