# What C++ compiler option do i use to trigger array out of bounds error?

Tags: c++, arrays

There is an array out of bounds issue and a missing delete [] in the code below.

Compiling code with the following options does not trigger any errors:

`g++ -std=c++2a -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-all test.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() { std::cout << "Base()\n";  }
    ~Base() { std::cout << "~Base()\n"; }
   int m_counter;
};


class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived() { std::cout << "Derived()\n"; }
    ~Derived() { std::cout << "~Derived()\n"; }
};


int main() {
    Base* b = new Derived[10];
    std::cout << b[10].m_counter << '\n';
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Any pointers as to what I could be missing here?

Comment: I assume `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak` would work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308104/static-bound-checking-for-array-in-c

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior . Undefined Behavior is Undefined. "It works fine (so far)" is one possible result of UB, since any result is possible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat compiling with the options you suggest, did not trigger any compile time error.

However, at run time, the following response was seen

```text
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/home/saifi/a.out+0x1315) in main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c087fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: @inout It's hard to detect such problems at compile-time, but those flags make it possible to detect them at runtime.

Comment: I'd recommend using valgrind, it catches more

Comment: @B.Go thanks for the links. 

it seems to suggest that "Bounds checking is not a part of raw arrays (or even std::vector)." 

Is that correct interpretation ?

Comment: @aschepler the link you highlight, discusses 'undefined behaviour' in depth.

What i'm wondering is, we are close to C++20 release and we still unable to address this issue.

Comment: Using vector::at will perform bounds checking, operator[] does not need to (though vendors often provide a debug version of the library that does perform bounds checking on operator []).

Comment: @Lykos thanks. let me give 'valgrind' a try.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir does that mean 'standard library' container(s) are the way to go ?

Comment: compile with debug symbols ( -Og -g ) and then just call your executable with valgrind as you would normally do. valgrind is a bit slower than AddressSanitizer but that should not matter when debugging.

Comment: @inout I think C++ (and C) will always have undefined behavior. Requiring an implementation to do something about many categories of issue would either be flatly impossible or would require sacrificing the "close-to-the-machine" efficiency that some real-world C++ uses rely on.

Comment: @Lykos
```text
 Invalid read of size 4
    at 0x1092DA: main (err_four.cpp:23)
  Address 0x4d8dcb0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 48 alloc'd
    at 0x483950F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
 
~Base()
 Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
    at 0x483A08B: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:585)
    by 0x109324: main (err_four.cpp:24)
  Address 0x4d8dc88 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
    at 0x483950F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
    by 0x109229: main (err_four.cpp:22)
```

Comment: @aschepler what you have highlighted is very logical. Thanks for the insight.

Perhaps it's the expectation that with two quick revisions to C++ namely C++17 and now C++20, array out of bound errors will be history. Guess, i was wrong.

Comment: @inout this means you err_four.cpp has probable memory access violation in line 24

Comment: If it was a local array (`Derived b[10];`), enabling optimizations (at least `-O2`) would give you a warning at compile time. There does not seem to be any equivalent with dynamic allocation, you could always try filing a feature request...

Comment: It's not that we're unable to address this issue. C++ has its own goals that may be different from other languages and it has the concept of undefined behavior for a reason. Adding bound checks to every single array access takes up valuable processor time which isn't ideal in many cases. If the people writing the C++ standard wanted to eliminate out-of-bounds errors it would have been done way earlier.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang thanks for sharing your perspective. it helps me see where the focus should be. Thanks once again !

Comment: @MarcGlisse i really didn't know about the connection between local array and optimization (-O2). This is an area i need to catch up. Thanks.

Comment: @Lykos Yes, line 24 is where i should be looking at. Thanks for the idea about using valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [-fsanitize=bounds](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)

Comment: Ripi2 thanks for the suggestion.

on executing the binary, the output seen is as follows:
```text
Base()
Derived()
... 10 times
0
~Base()
munmap_chunk(): invalid_pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

when the binary is compiled with -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak there is a more detailed description of the situation.